# Convert tuple to int in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm brand new at python, and didn't understand the other answers for this question. Why when I run my code, does `int(weight[0])` not convert variable "weight" into a integer. Try your best to dumb it down because I'm really new and still don't quite understand most of it. Here is the relevant section of my code

```
weight = (lb.curselection())
    print ("clicked")
    int(weight[0])
    print (weight)
    print (type(weight))
```

and heres my code for this script

```
lb = Listbox(win, height=240)
lb.pack()
for i in range(60,300):
    lb.insert(END,(i))
def select(event):
    weight = (lb.curselection())
    print ("clicked")
    int(weight[0])
    print (weight)
    print (type(weight))
lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", select)
```

Thanks

When I run the code, it comes up with `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'`

and I want it instead to convert the "weight" variable into a integer, so I can use it for math operations.

Full Traceback:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Casey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Casey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/s.py", line 11, in select
    int(weight)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'`

Comment: Your questions need to include your output, and a description of how it differs from what you expected. If an exception is raised, you should include the full traceback.

Comment: I changed it to include that, thanks though I'm new to coding and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

what you're looking for is

```
weight = int(weight[0])
```

`int` is a function that **returns** an integer, so you have to assign that return to a variable.

if what you're looking for is to reassign the variable `weight` with the value of its first record, that code should work for you.

If the item is already an integer then the `int` call might be redundant, you might be able to get it with just

```
weight = weight[0]
```

Comment: Just to help explain to @Casey Ryan what's going on here, `weight[0]` is an element of `weight`, which element you plugged into the `int()` function. So when you do `weight = int(weight[0])` you are overwriting the variable `weight` with just the first element of `weight`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you were using `lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", select)` here. This does get around the issue with `curselection()` returning the last selected list item but I would say using `lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', select)` would work better for this. Binding to `<<ListboxSelect>>` works because this event triggers after the selection has changed and when you go to call `curselection()` using this event instead you will get the correct output you are looking for.

Here is a bit of code that provides an example use of the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.parent, height=4)
        self.lb.pack()
        self.lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.print_weight)
        for item in ["one: Index = 0", "two: Index = 1", "three: Index = 2", "four: Index = 3"]:
            self.lb.insert("end", item)

    def print_weight(self, event = None):
        # [0] gets us the 1st indexed value of the tuple so weight == a number.
        weight = self.lb.curselection()[0] 
        print(weight)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

You will notice the print out in the console will be the current selected item on a single click. This will prevent the need for a double click.